# How to find data between two dates in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Query for finding data from now to 3 days ago not working.Although data is present but it cant retrieve data.

```
ViewsLog.where(:created_at=>Time.now..3.day.ago)

ViewsLog Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "views_logs".* FROM "views_logs" WHERE ("views_logs"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-12-09 08:15:21.586416' AND '2015-12-06 08:15:21.586513')

#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Comment: It should be `3.days.ago` not `3.day.ago`

Comment: I tried but even same response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have inverted the parameters - it should be

```
ViewsLog.where(:created_at=>3.days.ago..Time.now)
```

Comment: I would suggest writing `3.days.ago` as that would be the right plural form

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
ViewsLog.where("date(created_at) between :start and :end", {start: 3.days.ago.to_date, end: Date.today})
```

This should work well for you.

Comment: This is parameterized query.If I want to do like above?

Answer (score 0):

Create a scope in the model `ViewsLog`

```
scope :record_between, lambda {|start_date, end_date| where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", start_date, end_date )}
```

or

```
scope :record_between, lambda {|start_date, end_date| where(created_at: start_date..end_date )}
```

Now it will be generic for any two dates data

Now you can do

```
ViewsLog.record_between(3.day.ago, Time.now)
```